# Open Source IM/Audio/Video communication library

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, webrtc

What is the best Open Source library which has these features?

1. Peer to Peer communication

   - Instant message
   - Audio call
   - Video call
2. Server SDK - Desirable Node Js server, but maybe in another language
3. JavaScript SDK
4. IOS SDK
5. Android SDK

I know one library ([EasyRtc](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc)) which has above features exclude IOS and Android SDK. IOS and Android SDK is not open source. For it must be paid.

And [QuickBlox](https://github.com/QuickBlox) also not fully open source. Must paid for server SDK, but other SDK is free.

AND etc. I want use fully open source

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer to this, as any response will be opinionated.

WebRTC is supported by the browsers except for IOS and Safari, as Apple seem to have a problem with anything that's peer to peer, although they are rumoured to be working on WebRTC support.

Have a look at https://webrtc.org/ for code samples, tutorials and discussions on how things work.

For Android you should use crosswalk, as that will give you modern chrome capabilities. For IOS there is a project called iosrtc. https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc - this is not completely plain sailing, but with some perseverance it can be made to work.

You will also need a signalling server of some kind. PeerJS is at http://peerjs.com/ and is open source using a nodejs backend. There are other signalling servers, depending on your needs.

Be warned that while WebRTC has been around some time already, it is far from a simple drop in. You will need to do some homework to get the answer you are seeking.